# How to Retrieve User UID After They Have Been Created Firebase JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to retrieve the UID of a user I just created in Firebase using JavaScript. Below is my current code:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error, data) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  newusercreateduuid = data.user.uid;
  // ...
  console.log(errorCode + '   Error Message: ' + errorMessage);
});
```

I have tried a variety of callbacks including userData, data, user, and many more, but they all return null. I cannot seem to find anything online. I did find another Stack Overflow post using userData, but that returned null for me. How can I retrieve the UID of the user I just created?

Comment: listen for `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this:

You can access to the `then` method:

```
firebase.auth()
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(user) 
    // user information is available here...

    
})
.catch(function(error, data) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  newusercreateduuid = data.user.uid;
  // ...
  console.log(errorCode + '   Error Message: ' + errorMessage);
});
```

Also, if you need to control the user log changes, you can do this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    var photoURL = user.photoURL;
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    var providerData = user.providerData;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```

This will give you the user state after login. [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)

Comment: The user object is delivered via the parameter to the callback.  No need to reach into currentUser to get it.  And, in fact, currentUser might not even work that way immediately after signin (there was a bug about this at one point).

Comment: Good catch doug!